# Loss of roots in solving homogeneous first order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, roots, substitution, homogeneous-equation

To solve homogeneous first order ODEs of the form $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{f(x,y)}{g(x, y)} \tag 1 $$ the method seems to be to substitute $y=vx$, take an $x^n$ out of both numerator and denominator in $(1),$ cancel them out, and to proceed.

Wouldn't there be a loss of the root $x=0$ in this method? If so, why's it used?

**EDIT:** This seems to be a common problem in differential equations. Loss of roots is a pretty well-known thing, but I'm seeing multiple cases in practice questions here where both differentials and variables are blatantly divided across equations without a care. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: There isn't one; I was reading up on differential equations and this method was described using this equation, not an example.

Comment: Ok I see .....;

Answer (score 0):

After substitution you get
$$
xv'+v=\frac{f(1,v)}{g(1,v)}.
$$
This equation is singular in $x=0$, so the question of cancellation of factors $x$ is meaningless.

After solving for $x\ne 0$ one can examine if the solution $y(x)=xv(x)$ extends to $x=0$ as a continuous function or even as ODE solution.

Comment: Can you add some detail on how the equation is singular?

Comment: At $x=0$ it is not a differential equation, the order drops from one to zero. This is only for the equation in $v$, not necessarily for the equation in $y$. But the singular set $g(x,y)=0$ contains the point $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

Comment: If g has constants in it, it wouldn't be 0 at (0,0), right?

Comment: If $g$ was not zero at $(0,0)$, would it still count as "homogeneous"?

Comment: Oh, right, that makes sense. But then yes, wouldn't cancelling out the $x^n$s be incorrect? That would essentially imply $\frac{0}{0}=1$.

Comment: please respond.

Comment: No, there is no automatic value for the limit. As already said, for $x\ne 0$ there is no loss of information, and the behavior $x=0$ must be reconstructed via limits.

Comment: So... "Yes, it's wrong to cancel", is what you mean?

Comment: The cancellation is part of the solution method, there is nothing "wrong" about it.

Comment: But how isn't it wrong if the solution of the equation involves x=0?

Comment: Please find a demonstrative example for your doubts.